# Dynamically generate struct fields from SQL QueryRow result

Tags: go, struct

I want to retrieve all fields of the row and than render them to html. I know how to do it and here is a code for a row with 3 fields:

```
type View struct {
    Id         int
    Name_and_requisits string
    Reg_Date  string
}
func getViewById(id int) (*View, error){
    var vie View
    row := db.QueryRow("select id, name_and_requisits, reg_date from book where id = ?;", id)
    err := row.Scan(&vie.Id, &vie.Name_and_requisites, &vie.Reg_Date)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &vie, nil
}
```

But in my table one row includes about 20 columns and i need all of them with their names but i dont want to create a nasted hardcoded struct. I have an idea like to generate struct fields dynamically, from names of columns, and than use row.Scan on it. Any ideas? Maybe map is better for this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/query-result-to-map-in-golang

Comment: @StephaneMartin thanks, your answer helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> generate struct fields dynamically

https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructOf

But please: Don't do it.

Comment: "Don't do it". Hah, no kidding. People always come from Python and want crazy weird flexibility without realizing that Go is a statically typed language, and that it's a good thing.

Comment: your guidance is worthy of a +1

Comment: @RayfenWindspear you right, Python is my background:) And less flexibility is a good thing in Go, i agree. It's like crazy flexibility of Joomla with crazy hangs vs self-maded CMS